# Adding multiple li's to ul in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

```
const getSearch = async function () {
try {
const res = await fetch(
      `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=${apiKey}&q=${inputValue}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    // console.log(data);

    const dataArr = Object.entries(data);
    dataArr.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const city = value.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName;
      const country = value.Country.LocalizedName;
      const countryCode = value.Country.ID;

      const markup = `
      <li class="search-result search-result--${key}">${city}, ${country}, ${countryCode}</li>
      `;
      console.log(markup);
    });

    ul.innerHTML = '';
    ul.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

I am trying to add all li's to my ul. When I console.log(markup), the results come back separately, but when I insertAdjacentHTML() only the last li is displayed.

This is for search results, so the amount of li's is unknown for each search input, and I want the li's to match the number of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that it even worked once:

```
const getSearch = async function () {
try {
const res = await fetch(
      `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=${apiKey}&q=${inputValue}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    // console.log(data);

    const dataArr = Object.entries(data);
    dataArr.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const city = value.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName;
      const country = value.Country.LocalizedName;
      const countryCode = value.Country.ID;

      const markup = `
      <li class="search-result search-result--${key}">${city}, ${country}, ${countryCode}</li>
      `;
      console.log(markup);
       // try this
      ul.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
    });

    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

I would rather use `createElement` than `innerHTML`